# Limit posting links on facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, fan-page

I have created Facebook application for a year with php and JavaScript sdk, it is a auto publicator for my blogs and pages I have about 50 pages currently active, and as many Facebook pages corresponding to each site.

These pages are maintained by different people and publishers, we are a total of about 40 people working.

The application does is automatically post a link on the Facebook page pointing to the URL of the web every time you publish a new post on the blog or the Web.

So far everything worked perfect, but for one days have blocked the user had authorized the application to post ... I have been reviewing the publications database and saw that just stopped when it has reached the publication or the post 51.

I get the feeling that Facebook has established a maximum limit of 50 publications per user link in the total of your pages, which is normal if you keep a small number of pages, but if you keep for example 60 pages and want to publish a post in each one is a ridiculous limit ...

Anyone know anything about all this, I fear that all the work of months we have been broken ...